# Laravel throws errors when creating new project

Tags: php, laravel

Good day, I'm following the [Laravel documation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4) to get started with laravel and start up a new project. My problem is when I through with setting up everything along with add laravel to my path. When I run in my terminal "Laravel new blog" it runs but returns some warnings and errors such as in the picture below:

[image]

I ignored that and went on with the instructions provided in the documentation, which instructed me to run this command "php artisan" to see a list of laravel commands. When I did I got this warning:[image]

When I check to see the version of php available, this is what I get:

```
PHP 7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

Is there a way I can solve this problem? Thanks!!!

Comment: Youre missing php extensions

Comment: @Vilius is there a way I can get them install, and what about the second error?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/491629/how-to-install-php-mbstring-extension-in-ubuntu

Comment: Once that's done, run `composer install`.

Comment: @aynber once what is done?

Comment: Once you install required php extensions

Comment: @Vilius when I run `composer install` am I trying to reinstall composer(hope I'm not asking a silly question)? And after I have done can I tried to recreate the project?

Comment: no, you're installing installing laravel dependencies

Comment: @NathanSiafa install the required dependencies which you can see on your screen, and then follow laravel instructions from start

Comment: @Vilius thanks so much, I now got it working by following the instructions you provided.

Answer (score 0):

1. open your php.ini file.
2. Find to "extension=php_mbstring.dll".
3. Uncomment it.
4. Save your php.ini file.

and try Installation again.

Comment: thats a windows extension, hes using ubuntu

Comment: Run sudo apt install php-mbstring to install it.